# Angular 7 handle http request

Tags: angular

I'm having problem getting a simple http call to work.

I came from angularjs and AFAIK `.then` = `.subscribe`

So Here's my problem, Can I not use the `.subscribe` in my **auth-service** and instead use it in my **login.component.ts** and I want to get the **Http Status** also.

**auth.service**

```
const httpOptions = {
   headers: new HttpHeaders({
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
}

export class AuthService {
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
 mainUrl = 'http://localhost:4000/api/v1';
 signIn(user: User) { // this is working fine, BUT I want to use .subscribe in login component
    const url = `${this.mainUrl}/sign_in`;
    return this.http.post<any>(url, user, httpOptions)
    .subscribe(
    (data) => {
      console.log(data); // I want to get the 200 status not only the jwt token
      return data;
    },
    (error) => console.log(error)
  )
 }
}
```

**login.component.ts**

```
this.authService.signIn(userData); // how to use .subscribe here ?
```

UPDATE:

Here's what my angularjs code look like.

**auth.service**

```
function signIn(data) {
        return $http.post(url + '/api/v1/sign_in_2', data)
            .then(success)
            .catch(fail);

        function success(response) {
            setToken(response.data.jwt);
            return response;
        }

        function fail(e) {
            return e;
        }
    }
```

**login.ctrl**

```
vm.doLogin = function (userData) {
  vm.spinner = true;
  elixirAuthServices.signIn(userData).then(function (data) {

    if (data.status === 200 || data.status === 201) {
      elixirAuthServices.getUser().then(function (data) {
        vm.user_id = data.data.id;
        redirect();
      });
    } else {
      vm.authenticateErr = true;
      vm.spinner = false;
      logger.info('Username or Password is incorrect');
    }

  });
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are close, but you should make the following modifications to your service.ts. Don't forget to import the required RxJS operators such as pipe, and map, if you are intending to use them.

```
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

signIn(user: User) {
  const url = `${this.mainUrl}/sign_in`;
  return this.http.post<any>(url, user, httpOptions).pipe(
    // additional operations before returning observable
    //map(data => ....), 
    //catchError(this.handleError('signIn', []))
  );
 }
```

On your component.ts, you can return the observable by [subscribing](https://angular.io/guide/observables#subscribing) to it. The subscribe method handles the callback for `next`, `error`, and `complete`.

```
this.authService.signIn(userData).subscribe(success => {
   // next
   // .. handle successful response (status code 200)
}, error => {
   // handle errors
   console.log(error.status)
}, () => {
   // complete 
})
```

Edit: If you want to read the FULL response body, you can use the `observe` option

```
this.http.post<any>(url, user, { observe: 'response' }).pipe(
    //additional operations before returning observable
    //tap(response => console.log(response.status)
    //map(response => response.body), 
    //catchError(this.handleError('signIn', []))
  );
```

Comment: Thanks this is like how I did it in angularjs, but I still have the problem of only getting the `jwt` token how to get the http code status ?

Comment: Hey, just to check, are you referring to the getting the HTTP code status on success, or error?

Comment: I'm referring to the `success`

Comment: Hmm.. For success, wouldn't it always be code 200? Hmm.. Let me think.. If I am missing something here..

Comment: If you really want to access the response body (status code, status text, etc) even for your success response, you need to pass an additional optional parameter to your http.post() method. Let me update my answer!

Comment: The post <any> doesn't really make sense. You should be passing a domain model type to that so you get an Observable<DomainType> returned. Then the pipe is useful for performing operations on and returning an observable for example pipe(map(),filter()). The result of those nested calls will return an observable which can be subscribed. The subscription is needed to tell the observable that someone is waiting on the other end which will allow stuff to happen. That is why you return the observable from sign in so it can be subscribed to by your component.

Answer (score 1):

`subscribe()` is not the same as `then()` method in Promise. You need to just return the result of `http.post()` which is `Observable` object and then subscribe the observable in the component.

And if you want to catch error, chain `catch()` method in the service.

**auth.service.ts**

```js
signIn(user: User) { 
  const url = `${this.mainUrl}/sign_in`;
  return this.http.post<any>(url, user, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      tap(val => console.log(val)), // do what you want with val
      catchError(error => console.log(error))
    )
}
```

**login.component.ts**

```js
this.authService.signIn.subscribe(userData => {
  // do what did in login.ctrl
});
```

Comment: I tried this its throwing an `error` on catch saying `'catch' does not exist`., second is I want to get the value of the request in my service

Answer (score 1):

RxJs Observable

```
    signIn(user){
        return this.httpClient.post<any>(url, user, option)
            .pipe(
            map(res => res),
            retry(1),
            catchError(err => throwError(err))
            )
    }
```

then you can subscribe response and catch error at LoginComponent

```
   this.authService.signIn(userData).subscribe(res => {
       // do something here
       }, err => {
       // catch err here 
       }
       )
```